# Pop up remains to be opened on multiple clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery

```
$(".login,.login1").click(function(e) {          
            //$("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").toggle();
            $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
            $(".login_box").toggleClass("menu-open-css");
            var url = $(this).attr('data-id');
            if(url){
                $("#right_msg").html('Please login');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $CONFIG->url?>about/storesession.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        url: url,
                    },
                    dataType : 'json',
                    });

            }
            if($("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").is(":hidden")) {
                $("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").fadeIn('slow');
                $('div#aeromark').css('border-bottom','5px solid #FFFFFF');
                $('div#aeromark').css('border-top','none');
            }

        });

        $("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").mouseup(function() {
            return false
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).parent("a.login").length==0) {
                $(".login").removeClass("menu-open");
                $(".login_box").removeClass("menu-open-css");
                $("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").fadeOut('fast');    
                $('div#aeromark').css('border-top','5px solid #FFFFFF');
                $('div#aeromark').css('border-bottom','none');          
            }
        });
```

So i need is on clicking `.login` the toggle class should execute but on clicking `.login1` it should not toggle. So the pop up will remain opened.

How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!$(this).is('.login1'){
    //$("fieldset#signin_menu_popup").toggle();
    $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
    $(".login_box").toggleClass("menu-open-css");
}
```

Comment: NO its not working for me...check the edited question ....previously i didn't updated....